# SQLSTATE that returns an error but completes insert

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, innodb, database-trigger

I am trying to write an after insert trigger in mariadb that displays an error but doesn't undo the insert.

I read here [mySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) that

"If pval is anything else, p() first signals a warning and sets the message text and error number condition information items. This warning does not terminate the procedure, so execution continues and p() then signals an error. The error does terminate the procedure. The message text and error number set by the warning are replaced by the values set by the error, which are returned with the error information."

This is exactly what I'm trying to do. The trigger is just suppose to display essentially a warning, something along the lines of "insert successful... but hours > allowed_hours" but for my purpose it has to be returned as an error. Does anyone know what the documentation means by "If pval is anything else..."?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a test case that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @RickJames what issue are you referring to? I'm just asking if anyone knows the SQLSTATE that the documentation is referencing that signals a warning, sets the text and error number, and does not terminate the procedure.

Comment: Looking at [_this_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-error-reference.html), I would expect `SQLSTATE` to always be `HY000`.  See also [_this_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/error-message-components.html)